# Nginx configuration files structure

Tags: nginx, cache, conf

Where do I put specific domain configuration files on an nginx server? I've seen a lot of conflicting information. Does it belong in the sites-enabled folder? If so, do I put it in the already created (via symlink) www.mysite.com file? Or do I create a www.mysite.com.conf file? Or do I put the www.mysite.com.conf in the conf.d directory? I'm just trying to add some media specific caching rules particular to one website hosted on my nginx server (so not in the nginx.conf file). I just want to make this config file particular to a website. I'm unsure of where to place the config file and placing it conf.d under www.mywebsite.com.conf or in the sites-enabled under the same name has not worked. Thanks.

Comment: It really depends on what the main `nginx.conf` file looks like, based on its `include` directives. I personally don't use any other files at all for my virtual hosts and define all of them in nginx.conf, removing the include directives. For only a few vhosts, that works really well and I suggest you do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx packaging changed : the `conf.d` folder was used in old packages, `sites-enabled` / `sites-available` is used now with `sites-available` directory containing actual vhosts configurations and `sites-enabled` the symlinks to `sites-available` vhosts you want to activate.

So a typical structure would now be :

```
nginx
├── nginx.conf
├── sites-available
│   ├── mysite1
│   └── mysite2
└── sites-enabled
    └── mysite1 -> ../sites-available/mysite1
```

However, you have the liberty to do it whatever way you want, and even use none of these structures. Simply put the relevant `include` directive(s) in your main configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the files here.

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/site1/**

And do soft link

**ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/site1/ /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site1/**